# Run function on event based on class name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I`m trying to run different functions based on the image elements class name. The image elements are inside of link elements because, they are being used as thumbnails in a photo viewer div. My goal is to have a functions run when the On click function is ran for the photo viewer.

I want one function to run if the image has class Milk and a different function to run if the image has class Water.

So far I can access the image elements by class name but, when I try to set them to the functions they do not run. ex.

HTML

```html
<div> 
    <a><img class = Milk /> </a> 
</div>
```

Script

```js
var drink = document.getElementsByClassName('Milk'); //gets the elements wanted.
 
drink.onClick = function name; //does not run the function I set drink on click to.
```

Not sure if these have an effect but, I have a few other codes run on the link elements in the div. Adding classes, hide(), Fade(), and Delay() coding put on the links .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
var drink_arr= [...drink];
for(i = 0; i < drink_arr.length; i++){
  drink_arr[i].addEventListener('click', functionName);
}
```

instead of `drink.onClick = functionName`